# How to use this.props.history.push in React v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

this is Alex, i am new to react, while i was learning from the video, he was not using react v6, so i type **this.props.history.push('/add-employee')**; it won't work. Can somebody help me with the navigation in react v6[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ2XB.png). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use react-router-dom v6 (see advice at the end of the answer), you can use useNavigate hook to achieve this

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
```

then in your functional component instead of `this.props.history.push('/add-employee');`

```
//inside the function at the top
const navigate = useNavigate();

// use this in replace of 'this.props.history.push('/add-employee');'
navigate('/add-employee');
```

Some advice related to the tutorial that you are following

- Install same dependencies that are used in the tutorial
- OR follow another tutorial that is more up to date

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use a function component instead, where the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) hook can be called.

Then, navigating to a new route can be done like so:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
function MyComponent() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    function addEmployee() {
        navigate('/add-employee');
    }
    // return some JSX...
}
```

For this to work with class components, you would need to create a function component wrapper.

```
const withNavigate = Comp => props => <Comp {...props} navigate={useNavigate()} />;
class MyClassComponent extends React.Component {
    addEmployee = () => this.props.navigate('/add-employee');
    // ...
}
const MyComponent = withNavigate(MyClassComponent);
// now only use MyComponent instead of the class component
export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `useNavigate` Hook could fix your issue.

**The Code:**

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const  MyComponent =()=> {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const addEmp=()=> (
        navigate('/add-employee');
    )
    // return jsx
}
```